# How to code Keil-c51 and Simplicity Studio for c8051f340?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I'm going to build the following code for c8051f340 using keil-c51 or Simplicity Studio. How should I modify it to make it work?

The code itself cannot work when flashed.

```
ORG 0
     MOV A, #0
     MOV P2, #0
LOOP:
     INC P2
     CALL Delay
     SJMP LOOP

Delay:
      MOV R2, #3
      MOV R1, #0
      MOV R2, #0
DLP:
    DJNZ R0, DLP
    DJNZ R1, DLP
    DJNZ R2, DLP
    RET
```

Comment: What makes you think that the code cannot work when flashed? At which step in the course of compiling, flashing, and executing occurs which problem?

Comment: OP forgot to disable the watchdog. Silabs C8051's power up with enabled watchdog and a rather short timeout.